# Amazon Athena - Nested JSON issues

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena

I have the following json object for a person's attendance to conferences:

```
    {"conferences_attended": [
            {"conference_name": "dreamforce",
            "date": "2017",
            "city": "san francisco",
            "state": "ca"},
            {"conference_name": "RampUp",
            "date": "2016",
            "city": "san francisco",
            "state": "ca"},
            ],
    "last_name" : "doe"}
```

I have run the following code to create table pointing to where I have the data stored in s3

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.attendees (
      `last_name` string,
      `conferences_attended` array< struct<
          conference_name:string,
          date:string,
          city:string,
          state:string,
        >>,
    )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
      'serialization.format' = '1'
    ) LOCATION 's3://**'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Now, I have 2 parts to my question.

1) How do I query to access the data that is in nested json object?  The two queries below don't work and neither do many similar ones.

```
    SELECT conferences_attended
    FROM attendees;

    SELECT conferences_attended.conference_name
    FROM attendees;
```

2) How do I query to get back results matching only a specific portion of the nested json?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM attendees
    WHERE conferences_attended.conference_name like '%force%';
```

I am getting errors that leads me to believe I need to change data types or un-nest the data or something similr...  Thanks for the help and links to information supporting these types of actions.  Note, I have read the following links and found them helpful, but still not solving my needs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html and http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html and many others...

Finally, any advice or resources for the differences between 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' and 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the fields in your external table are not matching the fields in json file to which you are trying to point it.

As it seems, your table definition should be as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.attendees (
  `last_name` string,
  `conferences_attended` array<struct<conference_name:string,
    date:string, city:string, state:string>>,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://**'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

You have mentioned company_name and linkedin_company_id as fields of conferences_attended while you are trying to access other fields.

After this, you may access the fields in the following way:

```
SELECT conferences_attended
FROM attendees;
```

However, since conferences_attended is an array of structures, you need to mention array index to access the fields of that particular structure of array. So instead of this:

```
SELECT conferences_attended.conference_name
FROM attendees;
```

Try something like this:

```
SELECT conferences_attended[1].conference_name FROM attendees;
```

Now, if you want to parse all the structures within array and apply some filter on data, you may do it using the UNNEST function in the following manner:

```
SELECT 
last_name, 
conferences.conference_name, 
conferences.date, 
conferences.city, 
conferences.state 
FROM 
attendees CROSS JOIN UNNEST(conferences_attended) as t(conferences) 
WHERE 
conferences.conference_name like '%force%';
```

You may refer the following link for further references:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html